# Failing to push 500GB container every single time

Tags: google-container-registry

So, I've created a container with size 430GB and the push fails every single time with the same layer.

```
15d907c6c4d1: Preparing
....
15d907c6c4d1: Retrying in 20 seconds
....
15d907c6c4d1: Retrying in 1 second
write tcp 10.132.0.5:50149->74.125.133.82:443: write: broken pipe
```

I'm doing this push from GCP virtual machine, so network should be fast and stable.

```
$ gcloud docker -- --version
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
```

I'm quite lost how to debug the issue further.

Comment: Clarification please -- you executed a local docker build and are now trying to `gcloud docker -- push...` the container?

Comment: Can you please send an email to gcr-contact@ so we can get more information about the image you are pushing, etc... to find the root-cause of this push failure? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue is that the user you're trying to push as does not have write access to the Cloud Storage destination bucket.  The bucket is in the format `[region].artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com` and it uses standard GCS access controls, see [the documentation for further details](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#granting_specific_users_read_permission_for_the_cloud_storage_bucket).